# Gulp smoosher task runs fine on gulp init but won't update when running

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Im using the [gulp smoosher](https://github.com/gabrielflorit/gulp-smoosher) to inject content from a CSS file inline into a copy of my index.html file.

This is working fine upon gulp init, however when running I cant get the task to trigger / generate any updates from updating my CSS file.

I'm currently trying with the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var smoosher = require('gulp-smoosher');

var cssDir = 'assets/src/css';
var cssTargetDir = 'assets/build/css';
var htmlSrcDir = 'assets/src';

gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src(cssDir + '/**/*.css')
    .pipe(autoprefix({
            browsers: ['last 40 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cssTargetDir));
});

gulp.task('smoosher', ['css'], function () {
    gulp.src(htmlSrcDir + '/index.html')
        .pipe(smoosher({
            base: 'assets/build/' //target and inject from build CSS
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('')); //root
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(cssDir + '/*.css', ['css']);
    gulp.watch(htmlSrcDir + '/index.html', ['smoosher']);
})

gulp.task('default', [
    'css',
    'smoosher',
    'watch'
]);
```

Comment: i think the smoosher task should also watch css files and not index.html, what you should watch is source of change and not the end result

Comment: Perfect entre - thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I simply added a smoosher watch task for the cssTargetDir (the build dir) and that worked fine.

Comment: Hi entre - I think you should atleast put in an example with code on how that would look - would be much more helptfull for future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change the watch for smoosher to watch for css files and not for index.html

Remember to watch for the source of the change and not the end result

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(cssDir + '/*.css', ['css']);
    gulp.watch(cssDir + '/*.css', ['smoosher']);
})
```